# Add id column in self referencing many-to-many table in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have a Person class which can have Relatives which is a self reference many-to-many relationship(Relative is also a Person). I wanted to maintain this Person->Relatives mapping in a separate table. So, to create this relationship in EF, I did this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Relatives)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(c =>
                {
                    c.MapLeftKey("PersonId");
                    c.MapRightKey("RelativeId");
                    c.ToTable("PersonRelative");
                });
```

Now, this created a new table PersonRelative with two columns PersonId and RelativeId automatically as I planned. It also have composite primary key on PersonId and RelativeId.

Now, there're two things I wish to do here:

1. I want to add a new identity "Id" column in this new PersonRelative table for better performance. How can I do that?
2. Now, can I create a separate class for PersonRelative table, the way we have a class for every table. Because that would try creating the table again. So, I think I can either keep that fluent api mapping or the PersonRelative class. Is this correct?

I would really appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve two points by the following code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PersonRelative>().HasKey(x => x.Id); 

modelBuilder.Entity<PersonRelative>()
            .HasOne<Person>(x => x.Person)
            .WithMany(s => s.PersonRelative)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.PersonId);

modelBuilder.Entity<PersonRelative>()
            .HasOne<Realtive>(x => x.Realtive)
            .WithMany(s => s.PersonRelative)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.RelativeId);
```

it's how to make many-to-many relation in entity framework core, as it's not supported yet in core, you can use it in non-core entity framework too.

Please Note, if you want a new table mapping just for accessing data with navigation properties, then you can add property of type "ICollection" for Students in Relative Class, and the same for Student Class you can add ICollection for access Relatives from  Student

Comment: Actually I don't have two separate classes. I have the same class Person which also acts as a Relative.

Comment: So you don''t need for column called "relativeId" in person table, you can add new table called "PersonRelative" with cols (id, personId, relativeId) and then add fluent configuration mentioned above "the second line" with same syntax twice, one for -> personId and the other for -> relativeId
so it will be two one-to-many relations between Person and PersonRelative with different foreign keys.

Comment: @SachinParashar If you want a many-to-many relationships you're always gonna need a second table, aka a junction table.